# How to access MSMQ in C# behind load balancer (F5)

Tags: c#, .net, msmq, windows-server-2012

My issue is that I cannot access the MSMQ that is hosted on a Windows Server 2012 box that is behind an F5 load balancer. I am using the load balancer in an active/passive state to ensure availability.

I can access the MSMQ just fine when using the server name directly in the connection string but I cannot when I use the F5 VIP.

The following works:

```
FormatName:DIRECT=OS:<servername>\Private$\myQueueName
```

This however does not:

```
FormatName:DIRECT=OS:<F5 VIP>\Private$\myQueueName
```

I've also attempted to read the message queue using TCP to no avail:

```
FormatName:DIRECT=TCP:<servername>\Private$\myQueueName
```

Comment: Have you tried asking in ServerFault? I know you are trying to access MSMQ from C# code but it seems like this might be more of a configuration issue than a code issue.

Comment: `Robbie` does this have to do with a `Scalling Out` type of question / issue if so checkout this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4c367619-0fab-40e1-8c65-f13ccb9f0316/scaling-out-msmq?forum=architecturegeneral

Answer (score 1):

There is no MSMQ aware load balancer. F5 also cannot achieve that for direct queuing to servers. Since MSMQ works with multiple ports for its communication back and forth.

You can try the http option of MSMQ. That can be Network Load Balanced and communicates with single port.

NserviceBus has Nservicebus.Gateway which simplifies this solution. You can also use Distributor from Nservicebus to load balance amonst it workers. Nservicebus does not recommend it for load balancing, recommends only to use across wan networks.

Hope it helps.